# Previous window without refreshing the page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to go to the previous window when I click the back button in chat_user window without refreshing the whole page.
Below is my code:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">back</a>
```

Comment: Is `chat_user window` an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the previous website (also known as the page referrer) first and then open a new window with the URL:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(document.referrer); return false;">back</a>
```

After understanding what the OP actually wants, this should be the solution:

In javascript, add the following code:

```
function showHideChat(){
    $("#chatDiv").toggle();

    if($(this).text() == "back"){
        $(this).text("Show chat");
    } else {
        $(this).text("back");
    }
}
```

Now change the hyperlink to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showHideChat(); return false;">back</a>
```

Comment: @RajKaranam I'm sorry but that's not making any sense. Please find someone that is able to translate your problem to better English so we can help you out.

Comment: k I have chat windows I used javascript to open chat window without using urls.So,How can I go back to my chat windows using javascript

Comment: @RajKaranam Do you mean that you want `chat_window` to hide when the back button is clicked?

Comment: @RajKaranam Please edit your question and show us the div and the javascript code that shows this chat_window div. It may clear up what you want

Comment: @RajKaranam I understand. But I need to see the code for your chat_window div and the javascript code that shows this in order to answer your question. So please edit your question with this information

Comment: @RajKaranam The javascript code please. In your code where it says: `showChatWindowApplication( .. ){ ... }`. That's what I need.

Comment: @RajKaranam I've changed my answer. It should now do what you want.